# Jenkins github username password login

Tags: github, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins ver. 1.653 on OSX 10.11.3 using standard installer and added git plugin. I tried to create job for public project from github and it works. Now I am trying to create job for private repo using username and password but it always fails. This is log:

```
Started by user anonymous
```

Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/MyProject

> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/myproject/myproject-android.git # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/myproject/myproject-android.git
>   git --version # timeout=10
>   using .gitcredentials to set credentials
>   git config --local credential.username vandzi # timeout=10
>   git config --local credential.helper store --file=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/git428140271294555744.credentials # timeout=10
>   git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/myproject/myproject-android.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
>   git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
>   ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/myproject/myproject-android.git
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:766)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1022)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1053)
>       at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
>       at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
>   Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/myproject/myproject-android.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 143:
>   stdout: 
>   stderr: 
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1719)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1463)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:764)
>       ... 11 more
>   ERROR: null
>   Finished: FAILURE

Any idea what can be problem?

Answer (score 0):

Also had `ERROR: null` in the end, for me it was timeout issue. You can increase timeout for cloning and checkout like this:

1. Go to job configuration and find git section
2. Add -> Advanced clone behaviours. There you can specify timeout and check 'shallow copy' (which is faster)
3. Add -> Advanced checkout behaviours. You can set time out for checkout.